# Dynamically update SQLite row based on column values

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible for SQLite to dynamically insert/update values in the row of a table based on other columns within that row? Best illustrated with a simple example

```
CREATE TABLE family(first TEXT, last TEXT, full TEXT *magical specification);

INSERT INTO family (first,last) VALUES ('foo','bar')
```

And have the table automatically fill in the third column with a combination of the other two:

```
  first        last         full
---------  ------------  -----------
  foo          bar         foo bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_full
AFTER INSERT ON family
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.full IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE family
    SET full = first || ' ' || last
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```